# python, pandas, autocorrelatoin by groups

Tags: python, pandas

```
       fips  year        sc 
0       1001  1990 -0.707465
1       1001  1991 -0.707465
2       1001  1992 -0.707465
3       1001  1993 -0.707465
4       1001  1994 -0.707465
5       1001  1995 -0.707465
6       1002  1996 -0.707465
7       1002  1997 -0.607672
8       1002  1998 -0.607672
9       1002  1999 -0.607672
10      1002  2000 -0.607672
11      1002  2001 -0.607672
12      1002  2002 -0.607672
```

I want to calculate the autocorrelation of sc variable by groups of fips. I tried the code:

```
test=sc_itpl.groupby('fips')['sc'].autocorr(lag=1)
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'autocorr' of
> 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: How working `test=sc_itpl.groupby('fips')['sc'].apply(lambda x: x.autocorr(lag=1))` ?

Comment: Yes, it works. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
test=sc_itpl.groupby('fips')['sc'].apply(lambda x: x.autocorr(lag=1))
```